# Color autogeneratedcolumn cells using IValueConverter WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, binding

I would like to ask you if it's possible to change autogeneradetcolumn cells color using Converter?

My Datagrid in xaml:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding FillDG}" x:Name="ListHoliday" 
HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="186" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
Width="880" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10.4,103,0,0" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

codebehind:

```
Dim sql As String
Dim startDate As Date = dtStartV.SelectedDate
Dim endDate As DateTime = dtEndV.SelectedDate
Dim numberOfDays As Integer = ((endDate.Date) - (startDate.Date)).Days + 1
sql = "SELECT Enumber, HType, HStartDate, HEndDate from tbl_HolidayLog"
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn)
Dim dt As New DataSet
da.Fill(dt, "Holiday")
With Me.ListHoliday
    .ItemsSource = dt.Tables("Holiday").DefaultView
End With
For dayCount As Integer = -1 To (numberOfDays - 0)
    Dim currentDate As Date = Convert.ToDateTime(startDate.AddDays(dayCount))
    Dim formatedD As String = currentDate.ToString("dd/MM")
    If currentDate.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Saturday AndAlso currentDate.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Sunday Then
        Dim c1 As New DataGridTextColumn
        c1.Header = Format(currentDate, "MMMM") & vbCrLf & formatedD
        ListHoliday.Columns.Add(c1)
        For Each item As DataRowView In ListHoliday.ItemsSource
            Dim saDate As DateTime = item.Item("HStartDate")
            Dim enDate As DateTime = item.Item("HEndDate")
            Dim numberOfHeader As Integer = ((enDate.Date) - (saDate.Date)).Days - 0
            For dayCountHeader As Integer = 0 To (numberOfHeader - 0)
                count(dayCountHeader) = 0
            Next dayCountHeader
        Next
    End If
Next dayCount
```

I don't have any name for columns because 4 of theme are from table and the rest (dates) are created programmatically. And I would like to color cells in those programmatically created columns. Converter could be like:

```
Dim V As SolidColorBrush = Brushes.White
Dim holi As New HolidayLog
For Each hitem As DataRowView In holi.dgMyTeamView.ItemsSource
    Dim hType As String = hitem.Item("HType")
    If hType.Trim() = "Vacation" Then
    V = Brushes.Blue
    End If
Next
Return V
```

But I don't know how can I bind this to each autogenerated date cell/column.
Thank you very much for any advice!

Comment: you can do it by applying style to generated DataGridTextColumn

Comment: Yes, I was trying to do that with:
'                <DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>'

and with :
'        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:ColorConverter x:Key="ColorConverter"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>'
- without any result....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set **`CellStyle`** of DataGrid which will be picked up by autogenerated columns cell.

```
<DataGrid>
   <DataGrid.CellStyle>
      <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}}"/>
      </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

---

**UPDATE**:

You can pass the **Column** to converter and color only in case Column is the one you want to color.

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="{Binding Column,
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                                    Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

**Converter**:

```
DataGridColumn column = value as DataGridColumn;

 // Check for property name here.
if (column != null && column.Header.ToString() == "Name")
{
    return Brushes.Blue;
}
return Brushes.White;
```

Comment: It works, but it is coloring whole row. I think I have to somehow give him the name for those date columns....

Comment: You can pass the `Column` to converter and put the code in there. See the update in answer.

Comment: thank you very much. Hmm, so if in my code autogenerated column with date is c1 I should pass that c1 ('Dim c1 As New DataGridTextColumn
                c1.Header = Format(currentDate, "MMMM") & vbCrLf & formatedD
                ListHoliday.Columns.Add(c1)' as the ""Column** to converter?

Comment: Yes and you can check in converter if you are interested in the column or not.

Comment: I'm calling that column in a converter:         Dim V As SolidColorBrush = Brushes.White
        Dim holi As New HolidayLog
        Dim drv As DataRowView = TryCast(value, DataRowView)
        Dim Column As DataGridTextColumn = TryCast(holi.DateCol, DataGridTextColumn)
        If drv IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim dt As String = String.Format(drv("HType").ToString)
            If dt = "Vacation" Then
                If Column IsNot Nothing Then
                    V = Brushes.Blue
                End If
            End If
        End If
        Return V
But cells are blank.

Comment: I was trying everything and no effect. I'm calling that c1 column in converter but no result. Also I was trying to compare those c1 headers with dates in HStadDate and HEndDate columns to color only those which are connected with but same - no result....

Comment: I haven't worked on VB. But it's working fine at my end with C# code. I have update the post with it and see if you can convert it to VB and works for you.

Comment: Thank you very much. Well I've add your code (in VB) and nothing... I have property:     Private _DateCol As DataGridTextColumn
    Public Property DateCol() As DataGridTextColumn
        Get
            Return _DateCol
        End Get
        Set(value As DataGridTextColumn)
            _DateCol = value
  End Set
    End Property
and in FillDG code                 Dim c1 As New DataGridTextColumn
c1.Header = Format(currentDate, "MMMM") & vbCrLf & formatedD
ListHoliday.Columns.Add(c1)
 **_DateCol = c1** and "Name" will be holi.DateCol? Apologize for that...I'm trying to understand everything.

Comment: You have to replace `Name` with header of column name which you want to draw in Blue. So, in your case replace `Name` with `c1.Header` value in converter.

Comment: thanks. Now it is throwing "DataGridColumn with Header 'August 18/08' already exists in the Columns collection of a DataGrid. DataGrids cannot share columns and cannot contain duplicate column instances." and it's from ListHoliday.Columns.Add(c1)...ehh. I huess I have to solve it other way because I cannot do it with my knowledge :(. But many thank for your help!

Comment: You don't need to add any columns from converter. Algorithmic wise - Just have to check if value passed to converter is DataGridColumn and in case yes check if header of that column is same as the one you set earlier. If both conditions satisfy return Blue brush otherwise White brush.

Comment: I don't know from where it is generating new column. My converter (converted to C#): HolidayLog holi = new HolidayLog();
DataGridTextColumn column = value as DataGridTextColumn;
if (column != null && column.Header.ToString() == holi.DateCol.Header) {return Brushes.Blue;}return Brushes.White;and this is from codebehind: if (currentDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && currentDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday) {
c1.Header = Strings.Format(currentDate, "MMMM") + Constants.vbCrLf + formatedD;_DateCol = c1;ListHoliday.Columns.Add(c1);

Comment: I don't know where is that "same column" cuz I'm creating them directly from here.

Comment: Most probably you are writing the second part of code (code-behind) in some loop. First loop add the column and on second iteration it tries to add the column with same header and BOOM. See if it's inside some loop or not.

Comment: I've repaired the code and it's working fine, but no color for cells at all...I don't know, maybe I'm doing something wrong in the code (well, for sure...). I will try to re-create it once again..